mapping values are not allowed in this context while deploying
getting error as mapping values are notallowed in this context
I have written a deployment manifest file and getting an error message.as mappling values are not allowed.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: my-deployment
spec:
replicas: 3
selector:
matchlabels:
app: my-app
template:
metadata:
labels:my-appp
spec:
containers:
- image: nginx
name: my-ngnix
ports:
- containerPort: 8080

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: my-deployment
spec:
replicas: 3
selector:
matchlabels:
app: my-app
template:
metadata:
labels:my-appp
spec:
containers:
- image: nginx
name: my-ngnix
ports:
- containerPort: 8080

The YAML syntax in your deployment manifest is incorrect.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The YAML syntax in your deployment manifest is incorrect. YAML is very sensitive to indentation and requires specific formatting to correctly express the nested structure of the configuration.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-nginx
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080

Apply the same using kubectl apply -f <filename.yaml>


